# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize Collection using "Add"

Tags: c#, json.net

Sorry for my English

When object has some "side effect" to change the property,
Result not same as before deserialize,

I know shouldn't serialize object has "side effect",
But i need walk around as this moment

Json:

```
 {
   "SerializeBar": "bar1,bar2",
   "Bar": [
      "bar1",
      "bar2"  <-- only has 2 item
   ]
 }
```

Deserialize:

```
var deserialzedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);

deserialzedObject.Bar.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
//bar1
//bar2
//bar1 <-- why JsonConvert using "Add", not replace WHOLE List
//bar2

Console.WriteLine(deserialzedObject.SerializeBar);
//bar1,bar2,bar1,bar2
```

Model:

```
class Model
{
    public string SerializeBar
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", Bar); }
        set { Bar = value.Split(',').ToList(); }
    }
    public List<string> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

PS: not accept answer attribute [JsonIgnore], or reorder Property position because real case is to complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `JsonSerializerSettings`

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
});
```